# How to detect on CI if there is Prisma schema change but I forgot to create a migration file?

Tags: migration, prisma

Ok, let's say

1. I changed Prisma schema and ran `yarn prisma migrate dev` and created a migration.
2. I noticed there was a typo in schema, so I fixed it
3. I forgot to run `yarn prisma migrate dev` again after fixing a typo, so no migration was created for this change.

And this mistake went to a pull request. And it will be merged if nobody notice this mistake.

And this point, how can CI detects there is a schema change but no migration for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just decided to use Circle CI's `no_output_timeout: 1m` option on `run`. and just run `yarn prisma migrate dev` with `postgres` docker image on CI.

So, if there is no unsynced stuff between schema and migration, it will pass.
If not, the promft will wait for user's input to get new migration name, so Circle CI's timeout kicks in here and it will make it fail. So we're able to know there was a mistake.

It works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

We use `prisma migrate diff` to accomplish this in CI:

```
npx prisma migrate dev && npx prisma migrate diff --from-schema-datamodel ./prisma/schema.prisma --to-schema-datasource ./prisma/schema.prisma | grep -q 'No difference detected'
```

Logic:

1. Run migrations
2. Detect any schema diff from the data model (`--from-schema-datamodel`) to the applied schema (`--to-schema-datasource`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation for Github Actions to check if the schema was changed and you forgot to create the migration files in Prisma

(PS: change the working_directory according to your project)

```yaml
name: Run PR checks

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - "main"

jobs:
  checks:
    name: Run checks
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 5s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
    permissions:
      contents: "read"
      id-token: "write"
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          cache: "yarn"
          cache-dependency-path: "./api/yarn.lock"
          node-version: "18.x"

      - name: Install deps
        working-directory: ./api
        run: yarn

      - name: Check if prisma migration is updated
        working-directory: ./api
        run: |-
          npx prisma migrate diff --exit-code \
            --from-migrations ./prisma/migrations \
            --to-schema-datamodel ./prisma/schema.prisma \
            --shadow-database-url ${{env.DATABASE_URL}}
```