# Prisma CLI command like Django's `makemigrations --check`

Tags: prisma

In CI(GitHub Actions), I want to check if schema changed without migration generated.
There is exact command what I want in Django, `./manage.py makemigrations --check`, but I cannot found such command in Prisma.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-makemigrations-check

What would be the best way to check ungenerated migration with Prisma?

Comment: There is a similar Stack Overflow questions which has an anwer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72999362/how-to-detect-on-ci-if-there-is-prisma-schema-change-but-i-forgot-to-create-a-mi
Does this solve it for you?

Comment: @NurulSundarani Exactly. I appreciate it.

Comment: @NurulSundarani The question helped me, but I wonder if the checking process can be done without additional container. I want the process to be light as possible. It seems the amswer posted below closes my intention more. Thank you, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you want to compare you can use `prisma migrate diff` for this.

`prisma migrate diff --from-schema-datamodel --to-schema-datasource --exit-code`

`prisma migrate diff --from-migrations --to-schema-datasource --exit-code`

`prisma migrate diff --from-migrations --to-schema-datamodel --exit-code`

This will compare the state of the two sides with each other. If they are the same it will exit with 0 if there are differences with 2.

See the command docs here: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/command-reference#migrate-diff